# What is the correct way to access the K8S dashboard?

Tags: https, kubernetes, dashboard

## Question

It is not clear how to access the dashboard with HTTPS and cannot find a clear documentation (it just tells to use kubectl proxy). So what is the way to access the dashboard with HTTPS?

[Kubernetes Dashboard GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) tells:

> The shortcut http://localhost:8001/ui is deprecated. Use the full proxy URL shown above.

[K8S Dashboard Recommended Setup](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation#recommended-setup) or 
[K8S Dashboard FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/FAQ) do not tell how to access the dashboard without proxy.

> **I'm accessing Dashboard over HTTPS**
>   The reason why /ui redirect does not work for HTTPS is that it hasn't yet been updated in the core repository. You can track https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/53046#discussion_r145338754 to find out when it will be merged. Probably it won't be available until K8S 1.8.3+.
>   
>   Correct links that can be used to access Dashboard are in our documentation. Check Accessing Dashboard to find out more.

---

However, the [kubernetes-dashboard.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml) manifest defines the service endpoint to the dashboard as below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

And the cluster IP (in my environment) assigned is below.

```
# kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.101.199.14   <none>        443/TCP         4h
```

Simply create a SSH tunnel to the 10.101.199.14:443 and access to it (https://localhost:8001) shows the dashboard.

[image]

So, basically, there is no need to use kubectl proxy and directly access the clusterIP:443 is the way to access the dashboard with HTTPS?

Kindly suggest where is the up-to-date and accurate documentation on how to use the K8S dashboard.

### Environment

```
# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T21:07:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T20:55:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, You would not want to expose your k8s dashboard to external world Since It's a graphical way to get access to your k8s cluster that's why the service type of k8s-dashboard is clusterIP instead of LoadBalancer or NodePort( Minikube uses it).

Now If you want to access the dashboard without exposing it to the external world.There are 2 ways which you have described in the question.

- Kubectl proxy (It create HTTP proxy to kube-api Server)
- Kubectl port-forward (it create TCP proxy to k8s-dashboard pod)

Comment: Thanks for the update. The access is only possible from the intra-net to which VPN access is mandatory, so not exposed to external world, however we must use HTTPS.

Comment: If you can use internal LoadBalancer then you just need to use `type=LoadBalancer` in the k8s-dashboard service file. It might solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Suresh. As I do not have time to test your suggestions, forgive me not accepting it as the answer for now. Will test when I get time.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, after having fixed the AWS issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039953/, I could use the LoadBalancer to expose the service.

Answer (score 2):

As no time to test the suggestion by Suresh, used below for now.

Get the kubernetes-dashboard service account token (given cluster-admin role).

```
$ kubectl get secret -n kube-system | grep kubernetes-dashboard
kubernetes-dashboard-token-42b78                 kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         1h

$ kubectl describe secret kubernetes-dashboard-token-42b78 -n kube-system
Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-token-42b78
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name=kubernetes-dashboard
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=36347792-ecdf-11e7-9ca8-06bb783bb15c

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:    <TOKEN>
```

Start SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -L localhost:8001:172.31.4.117:6443 centos@<K8SServer>
```

Use Chrome [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) extension to send the Bearer token.

[image]

Access the API server endpoint via SSH tunnel (local port 8001).

```
https://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy
```

[image]

Comment: Followed your instructions, got an `status-code 403 (forbidden)` - response...

Comment: @Markus the same case.

Comment: @KarimManaouil: In my case the container-creation for the web-dashboard gut stuck because the _coredns_-container also got stuck during creation. After solving the issue I could access the dashboard. I wrote the solution down [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049036/kubernetes-container-creation-gets-stuck-at-container-creation-containercreati).

Comment: @Markus Thanks for the link. In my case the dashboard and coredns are running. Actually all containers are running fine (I used Kubespray to setup the cluster). I made sure the clusterrolebinding is correct and it is. For me I get 404 error, resource not found !!

Comment: @KarimManaouil: Have you tried changing _kube-system_ to _kubernetes-dashboard_ in the url? My Dashboard was running under different namespace

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Markus. I have just confirmed and it is running in kube-system. I think it's smthng related to IAM (Identity and Access Management) but I have no idea how to resolve this.